# Bad Request in AJAX

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

I am working in a WordPress plugin. I need help in below AJAX code.

```
// On change division 
    $('body').on( 'change', '.division', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:localData.statesurl,   //http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
            data:{
                division: $(this).val(),  // I am getting value here.
                action: 'division_to_district_ajax'  //Do you need anything here ?
            },
            success:function(rss){
                console.log(rss);
                $('.district').empty();
                var $opt = '';  
                $.each( JSON.parse(rss), function(key, value) {
                    $opt += '<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>';
                });
                $('.district').append($opt);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                   console.log(errorThrown);  // Bad Request
            },
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json"
        });         
    });
```

From above code I am getting `Bad Request` in console.

I am attaching some screenshots of Network tab.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: where did you add action division_to_dustrict_ajax function??

Comment: What’s the code for handling the request? Have you looked at other questions about this error? The solution is always the same.

Comment: Thanks @ChetanVaghela, Here is the function `public function idonate_division_to_district_ajax(){
   if( isset( $_POST['division'] ) ){
    echo  json_encode( $_POST['division']);
    die();
   }
  }`

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie. I read other questions. But could not find any solution. Thanks.

Comment: Did you add this code : function idonate_division_to_district_ajax() {
   if( isset( $_POST['division'] ) ){ echo json_encode( $_POST['division']); die(); }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_division_to_district_ajax', 'idonate_division_to_district_ajax' ); // executed when logged in
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_division_to_district_ajax', 'idonate_division_to_district_ajax' ); // executed when logged out

Comment: Is there a reason you used a legacy Admin AJAX endpoint instead of a modern REST API endpoint to do your AJAX calls?

Comment: Thanks @ChetanVaghela, your solution is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it's sending JSON request headers, the old legacy Admin AJAX API doesn't understand this. As a result these are the cause of the bad request:

```js
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json"
```

Your endpoint might be able to handle that input, but WP's admin AJAX handler can't, so it never knows which action to fire in the first place.

You have 2 options:

- Remove these and adjust your AJAX handler accordingly
- Switch to the modern REST API and get a proper endpoint URL that happily accepts JSON and returns JSON, and even encodes/validates/sanitises for you if told what to expect

Some additional notes:

- `$('body').on( 'change', '.division'` is quite a broad event handler, I'd recommend limiting it down from the entire body tag to something more specific
- There's no checking of the response to make sure it is what you think it is, the code just goes straight into `JSON.parse`
- If no values are found or returned there's nothing to indicate that's what happened

But more importantly:

#### A Major Security Hole In The Code

**Building up a HTML string by joining variables up together in JS then appending it is awful for security**. It's one of the worst things code can do in javascript short of `eval`'ing code. **Use DOM node construction instead** and deal with DOM nodes, never HTML strings. Consider this a omgbbq high level priority fix. `$( '<option>', { value: key, text: value } )` is what the code should be appending, it's much faster and safer.

Here's a secure version, the browser will automatically escape and sanitise the keys and make sure no malicious HTML gets snuck in:

```js
const data = JSON.parse( rss );
const options = data.map( function ( key, value ) {
        return jQuery( '<option>', {
            value: key,
            text: value
        } );
} );
jQuery('.district').append( options );
```

It's also a little faster as the browser doesn't need to parse the HTML, and you don't have to worry about broken HTML markup either. Notice the `data` variable, we can now wrap it in an if statement and change behaviour if JSON parsing failed, or it doesn't contain what we expected it to. **Never create HTML by joining up strings and variables**, it's a major security issue, it's slow, and it's unnecessary.